# How to collaborate Jmeter Load Test Scenario

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, threadgroup

Scenario - System should able to handle 1000 simultaneous users logged-in, and 500 users also active at the same time in the system.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should use different [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) for representing different groups of business users so just add 2 Thread Groups, one with 1000 "logged-in" users and another one with 500 users which are "active" (whatever it means).

Then add [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers to implement your users activities (you can even [record and replay the test scenarios using HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html))

If you already have implemented these user flows and just want to divide 1500 users into 1000 and 500 doing different actions [within the bounds of the singe Thread Group- put them under 2](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) Throughput Controllers

More information: [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability)

Comment: Can't we use Ultimate thread group to manipulate this scenario?